instalar nvm en SUSE tumbleweed
Intente instalar nvm en suse linux.
No encuentro información, ayuda por favor.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Solo en español por favor.. y que quiere decir que instalaste y no encontras informacion?? que paso?? la pagina de nvm no te sirvio porque???

Que tal en el repo de nvm tienen un tuto en ingles
en fin debes descargar un .sh con cURL o Wget acá te los dejo:
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.7/install.sh | bash

wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.7/install.sh | bash

con eso ejecutado debes actualizar tu terminal. para que se agregue al $PATH
bash: source ~/.bashrc
zsh: source ~/.zshrc
ksh: . ~/.profile
espero te sirva saludos. ✌

si la vas a contestar, por lo menos, aclarale al usuario que este sitio solo acepta preguntas en español...
